# why is there no itunes radio on my iphone 5 with the new update?

Tags: iphone

with the new update IOS 7 there is a itunes radio. well i've updated my iphone with the IOS 7 and the itunes radio has not shown up. i was told that it only works for the USA users and not the canadian or other users. now why is that?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the contract reasons. My question would be why apple does not publish list of features that will not work after upgrade to save us the hassle.